# Is there a way to get a breakdown of timings for an HTTP request in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, http, httparty

The gem HTTParty and built in Ruby Net::HTTP do not seem to expose the breakdown of timing in the HTTP request.

For example, `curl` exposes:

> time_appconnect The time, in seconds, it took from the start until the SSL/SSH/etc connect/handshake to the remote host was completed. (Added in 7.19.0)
>
> time_connect The time, in seconds, it took from the start until the TCP connect to the remote host (or proxy) was completed.
>
> time_namelookup The time, in seconds, it took from the start until the name resolving was completed.
>
> time_pretransfer The time, in seconds, it took from the start until the file transfer was just about to begin. This includes all pre-transfer commands and negotiations that are specific to the particular protocol(s) involved.
>
> time_redirect The time, in seconds, it took for all redirection steps include name lookup, connect, pretransfer and transfer before the final transaction was started. time_redirect shows the complete execution time for multiple redirections. (Added in 7.12.3)
>
> time_starttransfer The time, in seconds, it took from the start until the first byte was just about to be transferred. This includes time_pretransfer and also the time the server needed to calculate the result.
>
> time_total The total time, in seconds, that the full operation lasted. The time will be displayed with millisecond resolution.

Is there a way to get timings such as DNS, TLS, SSL and handshaking from Ruby or a gem?

Answer (score 3):

You should use Typhoeus, which is a Ruby wrapper for libcurl. http://www.rubydoc.info/github/typhoeus/typhoeus/Typhoeus/Response

It will give you the timings you are looking for on the response object; such as appconnect_time, connect_time, namelookup_time, etc.

Answer (score 0):

No, Net::HTTP doesn't expose such information.

A possible (although not very practical) solution is to profile your script using for example [ruby-prof](https://github.com/ruby-prof/ruby-prof) to get the timing of each method call, and determine the execution time of each phase.